# Compare items in two lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings

I have a method which compares two lists of strings. If the strings, and only the strings, from `listA` appear in `listB`, return `true`. Else return `false`.

```
internal bool DoIdsMatchThoseFromXml(List<string> Ids, List<string> XmlIds)
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (Ids.Count == XmlIds.Count)
        {
            foreach (var hwId in Ids)
            {
                if(!XmlIds.Contains(hwId))
                {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

My initial unit test is passing (no edge cases etc. yet), but I was wondering if there is a more compact, but still readable, way to do it.

Answer (score 16):

So let me get this straight, you are trying to determine if list A is a *subset* of list B?

```
internal bool DoIdsMatchThoseFromXml(List<string> ids, List<string> xmlIds)
{
    return !ids.Except(xmlIds).Any(); // A - B = {}
}
```

Or are you trying to see if list A is *set equal* to list B?

```
internal bool DoIdsMatchThoseFromXml(List<string> ids, List<string> xmlIds)
{
    return ids.Count == xmlIds.Count // assumes unique values in each list
        && new HashSet<string>(ids).SetEquals(xmlIds);
}
```

I would avoid performing linear searches through this as you'd be looking at O(n*m) performance when you could be doing O(n+m).  Use set operations if you can.  Use `HashSet<string>` if possible too.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. These (LINQ?) methods are new to me! Care to explain the `xmlIds.Count > 0` in the second example? I'm not sure what this adds.

Comment: In the second case, you need to make sure set B is non-empty otherwise it will always be true which would be incorrect.

Comment: Hmm... with the non-empty check it is just the same as the first code example, except the lists swap places. So wouldn't the second example return whether B was a subset of A, just as the first example returns whether A is a subset of B?

Comment: The way I see it, if you're checking if a set A is a subset of set B, just remove all common elements from set A that's also in set B (`A - B`) and it should yield the empty set.  The empty set (as set A) is a subset of all sets so we need to allow for it.  If you're checking if set A is equal to set B, then provided that set B is not empty, removing all from set B all in common from set A should yield the empty set.  It's unlikely that both your lists will be empty so I've omitted that check (you can certainly add it if you wish).

Comment: But in example 2, set B could just be a subset of set A. What if A = {1,2,3,4} and B = {1,2}? Apologies if I'm missing the obvious here!

Comment: Ah, yeah you're right, in that case, it would require some modifications.

Answer (score 6):

If you can use LINQ, I think you can do

```
internal bool DoIdsMatchThoseFromXml(List<string> Ids, List<string> XmlIds)
{
    return 
        Ids.Count == XmlIds.Count &&
        Ids.All(XmlIds.Contains) &&
        XmlIds.All(Ids.Contains);
}
```

to achieve the same result.

Comment: Perhaps `Ids.All(XmlIds.Contains)` might sound a bit Yoda-like, but I think it's still readable.

Comment: :-) Yoda like it does indeed sound

Answer (score 4):

This uses no LINQ, just methods defined on `List<T>`:

```
    internal static bool DoIdsMatchThoseFromXml(List<string> Ids, List<string> XmlIds)
    {
        return Ids.TrueForAll(XmlIds.Contains) && XmlIds.TrueForAll(Ids.Contains);
    }
```

Comment: I like how clean this one is.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions proposed by Jeff and w0lf are very fine, but have you considered simply rearranging your code a little bit? Because even though the following does O(M*N), your question was about readability, not performance, and I think that people unfamiliar with linq will find this more graspable:

```
internal bool DoIdsMatchThoseFromXml(List<string> Ids, List<string> XmlIds)
{
    if (Ids.Count != XmlIds.Count)
        return false;
    foreach (var hwId in Ids)
        if(!XmlIds.Contains(hwId))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm no LINQ expert, but I found them eminently readable. LINQ is about describing intent (what) over implementation (how). Gory internals is why we've invented higher-level languages and libraries.

Comment: I have to admit you are right.  So, I will reword my answer a little bit. I am changing "people not awfully familiar with linq will find this more readable" to "people unfamiliar with linq will find this more graspable".

Answer (score 2):

This is more compact, but also performs better:

```
internal bool DoIdsMatchThoseFromXml(List<string> Ids, List<string> XmlIds) {
  if (Ids.Count != XmlIds.Count) return false;
  HashSet<string> xmlIds = new HashSet<string>(XmlIds);
  return Ids.All(id => xmlIds.Contains(id));
}
```

This is close to O(n), compared to the original O(n*n).

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the two lists and then return the SequenceEqual method you can do it all in three lines of code.  SequenceEqual returns whether or not two Lists have the same items in the same order (hence the sorting before the comparing).

```
    internal bool DoIdsMatchThoseFromXml(List<string> Ids, List<string> XmlIds)
    {
        Ids.Sort();
        XmlIds.Sort();

        return Ids.SequenceEqual(XmlIds);
    }
```